# Why is the Cold Miss Rate for a Cache Memory not affected by increasing or decreasing the capacity or associativity of the cache memory?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Have a doubt about Compulsory/Cold misses for a Cache Memory.
My knowledge about a compulsory miss is that **It is the very first access to a block , independent of the cache size.**

Cold Misses are affected by increasing/decreasing the block size. Here is my understanding, which seems to fit.

```
By increasing the block size, the number of blocks in the cache should 
reduce, assuming the size of the cache is constant here. Therefore there
would be decreased number of first time requests for each block. Hence the 
cold miss should decrease.

Correspondingly if the block size is decreased, the number of blocks would 
increase, and hence the number of requets to access blocks for the first 
time would also increase.
```

But I am not able to understand how it is **Not Affected** by Increasing or Decreasing the Cache Size OR Increasing/Decreasing the associativity of the cache !!

```
If the Cache Size increases, then the number of blocks also increase. So
the cold misses should increases, as more number of empty blocks would
be requested for the first time ???

Similarly if the Cache Size is Decreased, the number of blocks would
decrease which would have to be probed for the first time ??
```

My same doubt applies to increasing/decreasing the associativity as well.

Looking for a better understanding of this.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

Yes, increasing the size of each block decreases the total number of blocks touched by a given workload if there's any spatial locality.  But changing the size or associativity doesn't.  Remember we're only talking about compulsory misses, not conflict or capacity misses.

I had to take a guess on what exactly you're mixed up on, but this might be it:

In a larger cache, it takes more misses to "fill" the cache (so most ways of most sets are valid).  But that's not what compulsory misses counts.  **Compulsory doesn't mean misses that don't require evictions**.

If you had a small that fills up quickly, it still counts as a compulsory miss when the workload touches a block it hasn't touched before, even if the cache has to evict something to make room for it.  From the cache's perspective, a compulsory miss looks the same as a conflict or capacity miss.  **A cache itself can't tell the difference between capacity / conflict / compulsory misses**.

A compulsory miss is one that increasing the size or associativity couldn't have avoided.  You need to be able to keep track of the whole workload to determine that.  A limited capacity cache of course can't do that, because that's not what it's for.

Comment: @Ankit: Is that what you were getting mixed up on?

Comment: I understand that despite associativity, cache size, or block size change, compulsory misses will be there. But my doubt relates to what factors cause an increase or decrease in the compulsory miss rate. You said "A compulsory miss is one that increasing the size or associativity couldn't have avoided." If we tweak the block size, the workload may do inital touchdown on more or less no of blocks. But isn't it so the same case with tweaking the capacity or associativity of the cache ?

Comment: @Ankit: No, all that matters is which aligned block of physical memory each access of the workload touches.  With larger blocks, two nearby accesses might be in the same block.  Cache size and associativity have nothing to with breaking up physical memory into 64-byte blocks.  **Imagine doing a histogram of memory accesses with larger or smaller bins.  How many bins have non-zero counts?  That's the number of compulsory misses.**